# python - subprocess command and output (linux command)

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, output

I have a command as follows, it gives me the cpu, memory and disk sizes in the linux system. I want to embed it in python code and get output.

But somehow I could not use escape characters properly and get output. What is the most practical way you use for this?

```
echo "CPU `LC_ALL=C top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | awk '{print 100 - $1}'`% RAM `free -m | awk '/Mem:/ { printf("%3.1f%%", $3/$2*100) }'` HDD `df -h /store | awk '/\// {print $(NF-1)}'`"
```

(We can ignore the echo.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a r before the command string like this:

```
r"CPU `LC_ALL=C top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | awk '{print 100 - $1}'`% RAM `free -m | awk '/Mem:/ { printf("%3.1f%%", $3/$2*100) }'` HDD `df -h /store | awk '/\// {print $(NF-1)}'`"
```

Comment: I tried that and does not work for me;
```
a = subprocess.check_output(r"CPU `LC_ALL=C top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | awk '{print 100 - $1}'`% RAM `free -m | awk '/Mem:/ { printf("%3.1f%%", $3/$2*100) }'` HDD `df -h /store | awk '/\// {print $(NF-1)}'`", shell=True) ```

Comment: It doesn't because there's double quotes in the command too